# How to use **kwargs to fill in format parameters automatically

Tags: python

I want to automate/simplyfy this:

```
def test(stream, tag):
    subprocess.call('git submodule checkout {stream}-{tag}'.format(stream=stream, tag=tag))
```

i.e. I want to get rid of stream=stream and tag=tag and somehow make use of something like **kwargs. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe a fancy GIT frontend/automation module?

Comment: It's a bit of an academic question. I just noticed that I wrote "stream=stream" and that the same keyword is in the function header, so I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents: don't abuse `**kwargs`, it should be used only if the number of parameters is not known *a priori*.

Here are some approaches not involving `**kwargs` :

### Easy

If your concern is length of line, you can save space by using implicit order:

```
def test(stream, tag):
    subprocess.call('git submodule checkout {}-{}'.format(stream, tag))
```

This comes at the price of format string readability, but for a one-liner it might just do it.

### Object Style

Wrap the parameters in a `Checkout` object:

```
class Checkout:
    def __init__(self, stream, tag):
        self.stream = stream
        self.tag = tag

#...

def test(checkout):
    subprocess.call('git submodule checkout {0.stream}-{0.tag}'.format(checkout))
```

or even:

```
class Checkout:
    def __init__(self, stream, tag):
        self.stream = stream
        self.tag = tag

    def test(self):
        subprocess.call('git submodule checkout {0.stream}-{0.tag}'.format(self))
```

This is verbose, but the `Checkout` object is more than a simple wrapper, it might be reused somewhere else or serialized.

Comment: The first one seems ideal here. The problem is that the OP didn't want to have to repeat `stream` and `tag` 4 times apiece. You've cut them in half, and you've left easily-understandable code and a nice inspectable function signature.

Comment: Your format string is the equivalent of `'git submodule checkout {0.stream}-{1.tag}'.format(checkout)`, which won't work because there is only one positional argument to format. You need to explicitly add the numnber of the argument to make it work: `'git submodule checkout {0.stream}-{0.tag}'.format(checkout)`

Comment: I agree on the overuse of **kwargs. I guess I ave overused, and have seen it being overused a lot.

Comment: The object style is interesting (even though in this specific case the first solution is better, I agree). I learned something, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
def test(**kwargs):
    subprocess.call("git submodule checkout {stream}-{tag}".format(**kwargs))
```

Now, you could add some default values, or raise clearer error messages.

```
def test(**kwargs):
    #set a default value for "stream"
    if "stream" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["stream"] = "mystream"
    if "tag" not in kwargs:
        raise ValueError("Please add some tags")
    subprocess.call("git submodule checkout {stream}-{tag}".format(**kwargs))
```

Now, when the tag argument is not set, the message will tell you so. Without this code, the only information you get is a KeyError with the name of the missing key.

Comment: I upvoted because I liked the way to do it. However, don't you require some kind of parameter checking for that the stream and tag keys exists in kwargs?

Comment: only if you want to add some default if they're not added, or if you want to make the exception message clearer when any of the required values is missing.

Comment: I probably should've worded my question a bit clearer: I don't want just **kwargs as my only parameter of the function. Maybe my use case is just silly but I wanted to learn something new about * and ** :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `locals()` to pass the dictionary of local variables:

```
def test(stream, tag):
    subprocess.call('git submodule checkout {stream}-{tag}'.format(**locals()))
```

Comment: While this works, it seams like a trick that makes you look smart, it's less obvious when you read the code, then just passing **kwargs to `"".format`

Comment: if you use `**kwargs` you can't be sure that the dictionary contains the two parameters used in the format string, but they will always be in the `locals()`. And when using `**kwargs` you _have_ to use named arguments, you can't do `test('spam', 'eggs')` anymore, you're forced to write `test(stream='spam', tag='eggs')` instead. That's a big disadvantage.

Comment: This is probably a taste issue, but when I call a function where it might not be clear what you're passing in, I usually like keyword arguments, bcause they're kind of self documenting function calls.

Comment: But that's not the case here, in this case it's already known which parameters the function takes, and the goal here is probably to avoid to duplicate naming all the parameters on the format call again.

Comment: The advantage of using `locals` over `**kwargs` is that the function signature is easily inspectable (e.g., `help(test)`)` The disadvantage is that the implementation is harder to understand. It's a tradeoff. But they're both trickier than necessary; I think more often than not, Stefano Sanfilippo's answer will be better. If the goal is to not type the variable names so many types, the obvious place to remove them is from the string, not the code (unless you're using gettext).